# How may I provide Google Analytics access to a 3rd party?

Tags: google-analytics, marketing

I have a marketing guy who is helping me with marketing my website. I want to give him access to my GA page so that he can see the numbers, for performance monitoring etc.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in Google Analytics. Your marketing guy needs a google account.

You need to add his account using https://www.google.com/analytics/settings/user_list and then you can give him access to infos.